# How to draw this diagram/graph using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I have this diagram, and I have tried to draw it doing every dot and line, but I was wondering, is there a way to do it with foreach cycles or something like that? thanks.

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far? Anyway you are not a new user anymore

Comment: @close-voters: The OP hasn't been online for 2 hours, i.e. he doesn't know what is going on yet. Give him some time.

Comment: @JouleV Questions can also be reopened.  In its current state it is unclear.  Therefore voting to close.

Comment: @HenriMenke The question is not unclear. OP informs us that he/she have solved the problem, but the code used is not optimal OP then asks if somebody may give him a tip how to solve the same with a loop or similar. OP does not ask you to write the code, just provide a hint, as JouleV has done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This does not provide a full code, but a hint so that you can shorten your code. You can use a `pic` for every group of dots like that.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\tikzset{
  dotcirc/.style={circle,inner sep=2pt,draw,fill=#1},
  pics/tripdots/.style args={#1/#2-#3/#4-#5/#6,name=#7}{
    code={
      \begin{scope}[local bounding box=#7]
        \draw (-1.2,0)--(1.2,0);
        \draw (0,0.2)--(0,-.2);
        \path (-1,0) node[dotcirc=#1] (#2) {};
        \path (0,0)  node[dotcirc=#3] (#4) {};
        \path (1,0)  node[dotcirc=#5] (#6) {};
      \end{scope}
    }
  }
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic at (0,0) {tripdots={red/ra-yellow/ya-green/ga,name=a}};
\draw[<-] (a) -- ++(.5,1) node[above] {\scalebox{0.5}{Traffic lights}};
\draw[<-] (ra) -- ++ (.5,-1) node[below] {\scalebox{0.5}{A colored circle}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A good answer to the question. :)

Comment: Thanks a lot!. And a question, I have hear somethimes that "pic" use, but I don't know how it is, is that a package? I know I am not new at this but there are a lot of things I still don't know about tex.

Comment: @J.Rodriguez You just have to read chapter 18 of the PGF manual. `pic` is very useful - it is a syntax in Ti*k*Z, not a package.